# MySQL COUNT() + half second COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have the following table and I'm trying to count the values from the 'name' and 'name2' columns but only add half of the count values if 'name2' !=null. And also create another column, as before, where it also checks 'active' value.

For example, my table

```
ID  |  Name1 | Name2 |  Active 
------------------------------
1   |  John  |       | True
2   |  Mike  |  John | True
3   |  Tim   |       | False
4   |  Tim   |  Burt | False
```

And the result, I'm trying to create

```
Names | Split_Count | Active_Count
Burt  |     0.5     |    0
John  |     1.5     |    1.5
Mike  |     0.5     |    0.5
Tim   |     1.5     |    0
```

So far I've been able to only count in integers, so would I be better off doing this in PHP?

All help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: For clarification, the query will ++1 to the name, but if there are 2 names in the row then +0.5 to each name.

Where as, Active_Count will do the same as above where ACTIVE = TRUE.

Comment: Can you explain your logic in more detail? Does Burt have 0.5 in Split because each time it appears in the Name2 column it receives 0.5? Does John equate to 1.5 because 1 for Name1 (record 1) and 0.5 for Name2 in record #2? Wouldn't Tim be 2, because it is in Name1 for records 3 and 4? Why is Mike 0.5 and not 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are after. Give this a go:

```
create table person
(
id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
Name1 varchar(50) default null,
Name2 varchar(50) default null,
Active varchar(50) not null default 'True'
);

insert into person (Name1,Name2,Active) values ('John',null,'True');
insert into person (Name1,Name2,Active) values ('Mike','John','True');
insert into person (Name1,Name2,Active) values ('Tim',null,'False');
insert into person (Name1,Name2,Active) values ('Tim','Burt','False');

select person as Names,
sum(splitScore) as Split_Count,
sum(activeScore) as Active_Count
from
(
select Name1 as person, 
case when Name2 is null then 1 else 0.5 end as splitScore,
case when Active='True' and Name2 is null then 1 when Active='True' and Name2 is not null then 0.5 else 0 end as activeScore 
from person where Name1 is not null
union all
select Name2 as person, 
case when Name1 is null then 1 else 0.5 end as splitScore,
case when Active='True' and Name1 is null then 1 when Active='True' and Name1 is not null then 0.5 else 0 end as activeScore 
from person where Name2 is not null
) t
group by person
;
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Quick question, is it possible to INNER JOIN with  another table? I've tried joining with the alias but I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Sure. After the `) t` you would do something like : `) t inner join someOtherTable s on s.names = t.person`

Comment: Sorry to ask again, I want to also add a WHERE date= clause after the JOIN. "Unknown column" is the error even if I add or remove an alias to Date. Thanks for helping me.